# Error while creating migrations table with laravel: "No such file or directory"

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When trying to run `php artisan migrate:make create_users_table` I get the following output in Windows CMD:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"require(C:\...\\localhost
\\sites\\makeitsnappy\\app\/filters.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
 directory","file":"C:\\...\localhost\\sites\\makeitsnappy\\app\\start
\\global.php","line":83}}
```

I'm running Windows 8. Laravel 4 and installed Composer, also ran `composer update` in the project folder. Same error happens.

Edit: Loading the application webpage, I get:

```
require(C:\.../localhost\sites\makeitsnappy\app/filters.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Also, there is no filter.php file.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since Laravel4 the routes and filters are in two different files: `routes.php` and `filters.php` not like in Laravel3 where both lay in the same file.
Check if there is a `filter.php` file in you `app/` folder.
The error occurs because the autoloader tries to load this file on application's startup to get the filters for the called route or global filters.

Running `composer update` won't help here because you only get the framework and it's dependencies via composer and it doesn't update your `app/` folder.

Comment: Hi, there is no filter.php file.

Answer (score 0):

did you do composer install? It downloads some important files. I think you missed this command!

composer install